# pass array to PgSearch.multisearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, pg-search

I am going to try using using PgSearch.multisearch in my app.

Is there a way to pass an array to PgSearch.multisearch() method?

```
search = PgSearch.multisearch('test1')
```

returns a record

```
search = PgSearch.multisearch(['test1', 'test2'])
```

returns empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search terms are separated by a space.  This will search for results that match `test1` and `test2`:

```
search = PgSearch.multisearch(['test1', 'test2'].join(" "))
```

To use an `OR` condition, you can initialize the multisearch:

```
PgSearch.multisearch_options = { using: { tsearch: { any_word: true }}}
search = PgSearch.multisearch(['test1', 'test2'].join(" "))
```